# how to check the logged in user is admin or user?

Tags: laravel

how to check the logged in user is admin or user, in multi auth.

Our controller is like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:admin'],'prefix' => 'admin', function() {
  Route::resource('user', 'Admin\UserController', ['only' => ['index', 
  'create', 'edit', 'show', 'store', 'update', 'destroy'], 'as' => 
  'admin']);
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:user'], 'prefix' => 'user', function() {
  Route::resource('user', 'User\UserController', ['only' => ['edit', 
  'show', 'update'], 'as' => 'admin']);
});
```

we want to commonize user profile blade between admin and user.
I want to get the role like ['auth:admin'] in route controller.

(It's better not to create new method in User/Admin Model.)

Do you have anything solution?

We are using laravel5.5

Comment: I don't know how to check the user's role is admin or user in blade.php. Do you know it? I use @if(auth('admin')), but it didn't work.

Comment: There's no such thing as an "admin" in Laravel, you'll have to provide more details on if you're using a package or if you've developed a custom solution to define what an admin is.

Comment: _Don’t_ use different guards for different user roles. What happens if you have a route where _both_ an admin and regular user can access it…?

Comment: @MartinBean - Correct. I consider it [an anti-pattern](https://github.com/JosephSilber/bouncer/blob/master/readme.md#checking-a-users-roles) to check for roles directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the most popular package for Larvel roles/permissions **"spatie"**, you can check role by:

```
\Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')
```

It returns "true" if the user has role admin and false in other cases.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to accomplish is not possible with Laravel's router.

The middleware is checked at runtime, so you can't have two identical routes. Your `auth:user` routes are overwriting the `auth:admin` routes.

Instead, you should either handle their differences in the controller methods themselves, or create a different route URI for each one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming users has a "role" attribute, you can simply get it by doing:

```
Auth::user()->role
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you changed your question, I'll provide this as a separate answer:

I would strongly discourage you from doing this. Checking against user roles directly [is almost never the ideal solution](https://github.com/JosephSilber/bouncer/blob/master/readme.md#checking-a-users-roles):

> Generally speaking, you should not have a need to check roles directly. It is better to allow a role certain abilities, then check for those abilities instead. If what you need is very general, you can create very broad abilities. For example, an `access-dashboard` ability is always better than checking for `admin` or `editor` roles directly.

If you follow this advice, you can use Laravel's `can` middleware for this:

```php
Route::middleware('can:access-dashboard')->group(function () {
    //
});
```

---

To answer your question directly:

1. Create a new PHP middleware class at `app/Http/Middleware/HasRole.php`, and paste this in there:

   ```php
   namespace App\Http\Middleware;

   use Closure;

   class HasRole
   {
       public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
       {
           if (! $request->user()->isA($role)) {
               abort(403); // or 404, depending on what you need
           }

           return $next($request);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Next, crack open your `app/Http/Kernel` file, and register your new middleware there:

   ```php
   protected $routeMiddleware = [
       // ...keep the others here...
       'role' => \App\Http\Middleware\HasRole::class,
   ];
   ```
3. Now you can check user roles directly at your route:

   ```php
   Route::middleware('auth', 'role:admin')->prefix('admin')->group(function () {
       Route::resource('user', 'Admin\UserController', ['as' => 'admin']);
   });

   Route::middleware('auth', 'role:user')->prefix('admin')->group(function () {
       Route::resource('user', 'User\UserController', [
           'only' => ['edit', 'show', 'update'],
           'as' => 'user',
       ]);
   });
   ```

Comment: I would argue against this if these "roles" are vastly different and not differentiated by just an ACL.  To me, it seems like the OP is not referring to access roles, but more of completely different user types. For instance, a client and a customer service rep would have vastly different user interfaces and a client should never have access to any of the customer service routes.